# Visual Studio Code debugger on react project with typescript doesn't stop at breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using the the built in Debugger tool in VS code. My launch.json settings look like this:
[image]

When I add some breakpoints to my code, it doesn't stop there. Is there some special settings required when using React with Typescript? On a react projects created by`npx create-react-app` it works without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You must create what is known as source maps. Without them the executing JS file has not idea where the breakpoint is in your TS file.

I am not sure on the build system being used to help any further.